# How to renew Page Access Token programmatically when expired using FacebookClient in C#?

Tags: c#, facebook, token

I have a website application that wants to integrate its incoming entries to our facebook page (not users page). Currently we are using short lived tokens or long lived tokens but still this expired and I need to auto managed this expiration of Page Access Token. Can someone help me here to provide a guide of how to do this programmatically using FacebookClient C#?

Answer (score 0):

Extended Page Tokens do not have an expiration date, so just use that one. You can´t extend a Token programmatically, it is only possible with user interaction.

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/